# Menu List Float Not displaying correctly in Firefox and Safari

Tags: css, list, navigation

I have a nav that is displayed below the images. I created the nav using the ul and li. The issue I am having is that in Firefox and Safari there is a space above the list while in Explorer it is displaying correctly with the flush against the header. Please help!

Comment: If you can put up your code or link the website, we're a lot more apt to be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the margin & padding on your UL, then giving it value. For example

```
#yourDiv ul {margin:0;padding:0;margin:10px 0 10px 0}
```